# How to set war name on deploy phase to Nexus repository?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have snapshot repository for storing snapshots with Nexus. Build pipeline consists from Jenkins with build job. The aim of this build job is deployment of an artifact (war file) to nexus. Everything works fine, but I want to rename output war. War filename has following structure:

```
artifactName-version-date.anynumbers-anynumber.war 
(example-1.0.1-20140925-120156-3.war)
```

I tried to set war name with maven-war-plugin in build configuration.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
   <configuration>
       <warName>${build.name}</warName>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Desired war name should be in format e.g. `example-en-1.0.1-20140925-120156-3.war1`, where en is build profile. Property `build.name` is set on value `example-en`. But this configuration is ignored and war file is still stored to Nexus in undesirable format.

When I take a look on build log, there is log about successful upload war file to Nexus repository and there is bad name of war file. So I don't know where wrong configuration.

Maven command is `mvn clean deploy -P en`

**Edit:**

Here is part from console log, where `example-en.war` is copied to jenkins workspace. This is correct, but in last step is uploaded war file with different file name.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.0.2:war (default-war) @ example ---
[INFO] Exploding webapp...
[INFO] Assembling webapp example in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/example/target/example-sk
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/example/target/example-sk
[INFO] Generating war /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/example/target/example-sk.war
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/example/target/example-sk.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ example ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/example/target/example-sk.war to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/example/example/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/example/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/example/example/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ example ---
Downloading: http://127.0.0.1:8082/nexus/content/repositories/example-snapshots/com/example/example/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
774/774 B   

Downloaded: http://127.0.0.1:8082/nexus/content/repositories/example-snapshots/com/example/example/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (774 B at 3.4 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://127.0.0.1:8082/nexus/content/repositories/example-snapshots/com/example/example/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-1.0.1-20140925.120156-3.war
```

Comment: First why do you like to change the target name in that way like `engine-en-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war1` ? The installation in the local repository looks like `example-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`? Why would you like to change the name into `whatever.war1`? Furthermore you can`t change the name which is used within a repository manager. What i don't understand is why do you need to change the name?

Comment: because every build for different profile create different war and I want to differ these wars. e.g. engine-en-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war1, engine-de-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war1, engine-es-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war1. Now there is not any information about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking into Nexus repository settings. Have you ever tried uploading anything manually? You'd see that whatever the file name is, after you upload it to Nexus repository it is available for download as "${artifactId}-${version}-${classifier}.${packaging}"

Unfortunately I don't have access to Nexus now and I can't check if it's possible to set it to keep the names.

The second approach would be to set the  tag to the desired format (since it accepts variables ${}), that would be workaround to Nexus naming convention (putting variables in version section is considered deprecated if i remember correctly though).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a plugin for this. Just add a property `<finalName>` to `<build>..</build>` like this

```
<build>
    <finalName>example-en-${build.name}</finalName>
    ......
</build>
```

Comment: No Effect...!! You mean to say there is no war file(example-en-<build-name>.war) created in the target directory? In that case, please add the console logs when you are building your project with the property I have mentioned.

Comment: finalName does not affect settings for maven:deploy. for that you need to override the configuration with maven-deploy-plugin